# Get-WmiObject from AD OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory, wmi

I have a simple problem that I can't seem to work through. I need to know what servers are still running server 2008/R2.

I know that `Win32_OperatingSystem`'s `Name` property contains the information that I'm looking for. I would like to be able to run `Get-WmiObject` against a collection of servers in an OU.

There are two problems that I'm having:

1. I can't figure out how to redirect the output of `Get-ADComputer` to something that `Get-WmiObject -ComputerName` can use. I think `Get-ADComputer` is outputting objects of type `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADComputer`, and `Get-WmiObject` is looking for type `System.Management.ManagementObject`. Here's what I came up with but it doesn't appear to work.

   ```
   Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName (Get-ADComputer -filter * -SearchBase "OU=Member Servers,DC=Company,DC=Com" | select @{L="ComputerName";e={$_."name"}}) -Property name, csname | select csname, name | Format-Table -AutoSize
   ```
2. My temp workaround: I was able to create a CSV that contains the list of server names. I was able to use the CSV to run `Get-WmiObject` against. However, the OU contains "dead" servers. So when I try to run `Get-WmiObject` using the CSV-list of servers that came from AD there are connection timeouts and PowerShell waits a period of time to see if the dead server will respond. This really slows down the operation & we are working to clean this up. Until that happens, Is there a way to only pass the server names that pass a `Test-Connection` to `Get-WmiObject`?

   ```
   Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName (Get-Content C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Servers.csv) -Property name, csname | select csname, name | Format-Table -AutoSize
   ```

Comment: `-ComputerName (Get-ADComputer -filter * -SearchBase "OU=Member Servers,DC=Company,DC=Com").Name`  The Get-WmiObject parameter -ComputerName needs to be given a computer name as a string, rather than as an object which has a ComputerName property.

Comment: That worked -- thank-you!

Answer (score 2):

Pick the name component first then it will pass it to the next pipeline object (select -object)

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName ((Get-ADComputer -filter * -SearchBase "OU=Member Servers,DC=Company,DC=Com").Name)
```

Note: *-ComputerName*: accepts a string object so you cannot pass a base type object directly to that.